# How do I add Unity support to a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nuget

How do I publish a package to NuGet that supports Unity (the game engine)?

Also, do I need to have Unity installed to compile it, or is targeting a specific framework version enough?

Comment: Why don't you download a package (.nupkg) that you know works, unzip it, and inspect the contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I publish a package to NuGet that supports Unity (the game engine)?

Just follow the instructions in [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/). Class library for Unity3D is nothing different from regular .NET Class library. It just uses a different runtime comes from [Unity3D's fork of mono](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono).

> Also, do I need to have Unity installed to compile it, or is targeting a specific framework version enough?

Yes. If your library uses Unity3D types, the project needs to reference assemblies, such as `UnityEngine.dll` and `UnityEditor.dll`, from Unity3D. If your library doesn't use Unity3D types, you still need to test it with Unity3D. Because older Unity3D targets .NET 2.0 and a subset of .NET 3.5. So if your library uses features only available in .NET 4+, it won't work with Unity3D. See also [Using dll](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html).

It's better to install [Visual Studio Tools for Unity3D for VS2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SebastienLebreton.VisualStudio2015ToolsforUnity) (for VS2017, [install VSTU in the VS installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2017#manual-installation) instead) and then you can target one of the Unity3D targets:

[image: Unity3D .NET targets]

As for the publishment of your package, I think you'd better [publish your package on Unity3D asset store](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetStorePublishingGuide.html) since it is officially supported. You may want to try this [improved version of Unity3D asset store tools](https://github.com/zwcloud/AssetStoreTools/releases) when publishing your package to the asset store.

Comment: _"Just follow the instructions in the doc"_ - as far as I can tell, the docs make no mention of Unity.  Also, do I need to target `UnityEngine.dll` if I'm not using it?  My library has nothing to do with Unity, but I'm being told it does not work in Unity projects because they require special NuGet packages _(which explains the existence of the popular "JSON.Net for Unity" library)_

Comment: As for JSON.Net for Unity, actually we use [the one on unity asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11347), not the one on nuget.