# Add dll´s from .nupkg to Unity Project without using nuget

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dllimport, windows-mixed-reality

I am trying to use Microsoft´s WorldLockingTools ([repo see here](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WorldLockingTools-Unity)) in my Unity Mixed Reality project. Therefore I need to add the Frozen World Engine DLL to my Unity Project. In [Microsoft´s Documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WorldLockingTools-Unity/DocGen/Documentation/HowTos/InitialSetup.html#frozenworld-engine-installation) they describe to do this via nuget. I want to add the dependencies manually like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447595/nuget-packages-in-unity) thread, since for me it´s not possible to use nuget (I have no network-access on that computer). I was able to extract the .dll, but if I add it to my project as described in that thread, unity still can´t find the dll. Do I need to do some further steps than just adding the dll to my Asset-Folder? If yes,  can you please tell me which steps they are? I would be really thankful for that!

Best regards!

Comment: `since for me it´s not possible to use nuget.` .. why not? Have you tried [Nuget for Unity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) ?

Comment: I have no network access on my dev-computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out the reason behind this misbehavior. The problem is, that there is a c#-Script within the nuget-package additional to the dlls which has to be placed within the WorldLocking.Engine folder. After that all Exceptions disappeared and it seems to work now! I Hope I could help anybody who comes across this Question.